# How to replace string to a byte in android

Tags: java, android

How can replace one item of Byte array in android

My code is it

```
public  void saldohext(View view){
    EditText tvBalanceBIP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHexa);
    int balance = Integer.parseInt(tvBalanceBIP .getText().toString()) * 100;
    int total = 65535;
    int diference = total - balance ;

    String StrBalance = Integer.toHexString(balance ).toString();
    String StrDiference  = Integer.toHexString(diference ).toString();

    byte a = Byte.decode("0x"+StrBalance .substring(2));
    byte b = Byte.decode("0x"+StrBalance .substring(0, 2));
    byte c = Byte.decode("0x"+StrDiference  .substring(2));
    byte d = Byte.decode("0x"+StrDiferencia.substring(0,2));

    DATA_CARGA = new byte[]{(byte) a, (byte) b,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
                            (byte) c,(byte) d,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,
                            (byte) a,(byte) b,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
                            (byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x86};
    tvSaldoBIP.setText(DATA_CARGA.toString());
}
```

and my device show me

> "value 250 out to range from input 0xfa"

Comment: You mean replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "out of range" problem is with trying to [Byte.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#decode(java.lang.String)) a value that is outside the range of the `byte` data type, which will cause it to throw a `NumberFormatException`.

From Java's [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) docs:

> **byte**:
>   The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127
>   (inclusive).

Now, let's take an example with your code by running it through the debugger:

```
    // I've hardcoded balance here as an example.
    int balance = 55 * 100; 
    int total = 65535;
    int diference = total - balance;

    // You don't need to call toString() here because
    // toHexString()'s output is already a String.
    String StrBalance = Integer.toHexString(balance);      //"157c"
    String StrDiference  = Integer.toHexString(diference); //"ea83"

    String sub;
    byte a = Byte.decode("0x"+StrBalance.substring(2));    //OK, 0x7c=124
    byte b = Byte.decode("0x"+StrBalance.substring(0,2));  //OK, 0x15=21
    sub = StrDiference.substring(2); //"83"
    byte c;
    try {
        c = Byte.decode("0x"+sub);   //NG, because 0x83=131 > 127
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        c = 0; //Byte.decode will throw a NumberFormatException
    }
```

As shown in the comments, when I try to `Byte.decode` "0x83", it will fail because 0x83=131 which is greater than `byte`'s max value of 127 (0x7F). Without a `try-catch` block, that's going to produce this unhandled exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range for
>   byte: "0x83"

which is the same as what you got (you were trying to `Byte.decode` "0xfa").

---

To solve this, try using Java's [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class instead, which will internally handle the conversions for you and will allow you to convert your `int`'s directly to `byte` arrays, skipping all the `String` conversions since, at the end of your method, what you need are the bytes for `DATA_CARGA`.

```
    int balance = Integer.parseInt(tvBalanceBIP .getText().toString()) * 100;
    int total = 65535;
    int diference = total - balance;

    byte[] balanceBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(balance).array();
    balanceBytes[0] = (byte)0x00;
    balanceBytes[1] = (byte)0x00;

    byte[] diferenceBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(diference).array();
    diferenceBytes[0] = (byte)0xFF;
    diferenceBytes[1] = (byte)0xFF;

    DATA_CARGA = new byte[] {
            balanceBytes[3], balanceBytes[2], balanceBytes[1], balanceBytes[0],
            diferenceBytes[3], diferenceBytes[2], diferenceBytes[1], diferenceBytes[0],
            balanceBytes[3], balanceBytes[2], balanceBytes[1], balanceBytes[0],
            (byte)0x00, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x86
    };
    tvSaldoBIP.setText(DATA_CARGA.toString());
```

You can even get rid of the `new byte[]` code by declaring `DATA_CARGA` as a `ByteBuffer` then using the available `put(..)` methods to build the byte array (which makes the code cleaner).

Comment: thank you very much helped the ByteBuffer for my project